# Updating multiple nested objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have nested object, and on incoming change I want to create copy of expenses object and  **update all timeSpent values**. New values are calculated from updated data, so I have to make the calculation for every timeSpent value. I can't find a way to do this.

I have tired creating copy of expenses object using {...expenses.byId} and making array from it with Ovject.values, mapping the data and making calculations. Then problem arises, values are nested, so original object gets changed.

I have tired to make a deep copy of the object, the problem is the same or I'm doing something wrong. If I need to go one level deeper in copyOfExpenses how should I do that?

```
 const state = {
    expenses: {
        byId: {
            k948zpnp: {
                id: 'k948zpnp',
                category: 'other',
                description: 'book',
                amount: '25',
                timeSpent: '2.5',
                time: '2020-4-21 10:48:10'
            },
            z9e8ipnp: {
                id: 'z9e8ipnp',
                category: 'food',
                description: 'pasta',
                amount: '12',
                timeSpent: '1.2',
                time: '2020-4-21 11:48:10'
            },
        },
        allIds: ['k948zpnp', 'z9e8ipnp']
    }
}

const copyOfExpenses = {
    ...state,
    expenses: {
        ...state.expenses,
        byId: { ...state.expenses.byId },
        allIds: [...state.expenses.allIds]
    }
}

let newInputForTimeSpent = 14
let newData = copyOfExpenses.expenses.allIds.map(
    item =>
        (copyOfExpenses.expenses.byId[item].timeSpent =
            copyOfExpenses.expenses.byId[item].timeSpent * newInputForTimeSpent)
)

console.log(copyOfExpenses) // changes works
console.log(state) // original data gets changed
```

Comment: Deep copying objects is non-trivial. Best to use a library function, rather than rolling your own. https://github.com/terrymorse58/deep-copy-all

Comment: If your object is composed only of strings/numbers then the easiest way to deep copy it is to convert it to json and back: copyOfExpenses = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First approach**

I know, hardcoding ids is a terrible idea.

```js
let newInputForTimeSpent = 14;

const copyOfExpenses = {
    ...state,
    expenses: {
        ...state.expenses,
        byId: {
           ...state.expenses.byId,
           k948zpnp: {
             ...state.expenses.k948zpnp,
             timeSpent: state.expenses.k948zpnp.timeSpent * newInputForTimeSpent
           },
           z9e8ipnp: {
             ...state.expenses.z9e8ipnp,
             timeSpent: state.expenses.z9e8ipnp.timeSpent * newInputForTimeSpent 
           }
        },
        allIds: [...state.expenses.allIds]
    }
}
```

**Second approach**

```js
const state = {
  expenses: {
    byId: {
      k948zpnp: {
        id: 'k948zpnp',
        category: 'other',
        description: 'book',
        amount: '25',
        timeSpent: '2.5',
        time: '2020-4-21 10:48:10'
      },
      z9e8ipnp: {
        id: 'z9e8ipnp',
        category: 'food',
        description: 'pasta',
        amount: '12',
        timeSpent: '1.2',
        time: '2020-4-21 11:48:10'
      },
    },
    allIds: ['k948zpnp', 'z9e8ipnp']
  }
}

const updateTimeSpentForExpenses = (state, newInputForTimeSpent) => {
  let byId = { ...state.expenses.byId
  }
  const newObjs = Object.entries(byId).map(([key, value]) => {
    return {
      [key]: {
        ...value,
        timeSpent: value.timeSpent * newInputForTimeSpent
      }
    }
  })

  for (let newObj of newObjs) {
    Object.assign(byId, newObj)
  }

  return {
    ...state,
    expenses: {
      ...state.expenses,
      byId,
      allIds: [...state.expenses.allIds]
    }
  }
}

console.log(updateTimeSpentForExpenses(state, 10))
```

Instead of `for of loop` with `Object.assign` you can use `Array.reduce`

```js
const newObjs = Object.entries(byId).map(([key, value]) => {
      return {
       [key]: {
        ...value,
        timeSpent: value.timeSpent * newInputForTimeSpent
       }
  }
})

for(let newObj of newObjs) {
   Object.assign(byId, newObj)
}
```

Becomes

```js
byId = Object.entries(byId).map(([key, value]) => {
      return [key, {
        ...value,
        timeSpent: value.timeSpent * newInputForTimeSpent
       }]
  }
}).reduce((acc, ([key, value]) => {
  acc[key] = value;

  return acc;
}, {})
```